# switch input between ng-value (one-way) and ng-model (two-way) binding

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of html `input` fields that can be bound either to their backing json content field (two-way via `ng-model`), or to obtain their value from a selected object in an html 'select' (one-way via `ng-view`), or need to be switched between the two forms. I'm not even sure if the latter is possible as I'm new to angularjs, and this is what this question is about.

I can get the initial `input` binding set up correctly for the switching-binding input text, where if it has null content it is bound to the select list, but if it has non-null content it is bound to that. I can also set up a `checkbox` for each that tracks whether it is getting input from the user, or from the `select` list.

What I need to be able to do: If a user starts to manually enter a value (or unchecks the 'use select list' `checkbox`), it switches binding to the text's content field. It also needs to switch back to binding to the `select` when the user checks the 'use select list' `checkbox`.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <label for="ddlSelectionList">Select from list:</label>
        <select id="ddlSelectionList" ng-model="selectedRow" ng-options="row as row.name for row in selectionList"></select>
        <div ng-repeat='text in texts'>
            <label for='txt{{text.id}}'>{{text.name}}</label>   
            <input ng-if='text.content !== null' type="text" id='txt{{text.id}}' ng-model='text.content' />
            <input ng-if='text.content === null' type="text" id='txt{{text.id}}' ng-value='selectedRow[text.listfieldname]'   ng-keyup='manual(text, this)' />
            <span ng-if='text.listfieldname !== null'>
                <input type='checkbox' ng-init='text.uselist = (text.content === null)' ng-checked='text.content === null' ng-change='bindSelectList(text)' ng-model='text.uselist'/>
                <label>use select list</label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.selectionList = [
        {'id': 5, 'name': 'row 5', 'field1': 'row5field1', 'field2': 'row5field2' }, 
        {'id': 9, 'name': 'row 9', 'field1': 'row9field1', 'field2': 'row9field2' }];

    $scope.selectedRow = $scope.selectionList[1];

    $scope.texts = [{
        'id': 453,
            'name': 'Input Text1',
            'content': null,
            'listfieldname': 'field1'
    }, {
        'id': 455,
            'name': 'Input Text2',
            'content': 'manual entry',
            'listfieldname': 'field2'
    }];

    $scope.bindSelectList = function(text) {
        if (text.uselist) { //set value to get from select list
            //??.ngValue = 'selectedRow[text.listfieldname]'
        } else { //bind to text.content
            //??.ngModel = 'text.content'
        }

    };
    $scope.manual = function(text, txtInput) {
        text.uselist = false;   
        //??.ngModel = 'text.content'
        console.log(text);
    };
});
```

And [here's the jsfiddle for the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/9n3evrbq/5/).

Edit: What I want the fiddle to do:

- user clicks on the 'use select list' for 'Input Text2', should then replace content with 'row9field2' (assuming row id 9 is still selected in the ddl)
- user manually enters data into the 'Input Text1' (or unchecks 'use select list' for that input): this should be reflected in the model at $scope.texts[0].content.

Comment: Not clear what expectations are exactly or what we should be seeing or doing in demo to replicate problem. If you want `ng-model` modified you have to do that in a directive

Comment: I want ng-model replaced by ng-value (and vice versa). 

I'll have a go at editing the post to make things clearer.

Comment: What should happen when you change <input> binding to view only? 
Shall it be set read-only then? If "not" where its changed (by the user) value shall go?

Comment: it won't be read-only... the value set will be stored by the select list. (via selectedRow and 'listfieldname'). the user needs to be able to manually override the select list's value, and that manually-entered value would then again be bound to text.content.

Comment: That sort of UI doesn't really make sense....what if user starts entering data and then switches the checkbox ...will lose what they already did. I think you need to look into using `ngModel` parsers in a directive. Model value and view value can differ that way

Comment: if they start entering data then decide they want their data supplied by the select statement then it's fine they lose their data. 

thanks, I'll look into ngModel parsers and writing my own directives.